# highchart not displaying bars chart while printing

Tags: highcharts

I am new to highchart and am using it to render bar chart on my webpage. But the chart is not getting displayed while printing. Only the X and Y axis is printing with values but not the bars on it. 
I am using IE8. The bar chart is visible(on print) in IE8 mode but its not visible in IE8 Compatible mode. I need to make it work on IE default mode i.e. IE8 compat. mode.

Can anyone help me in this issue.

I am adding a code chunk of my js function where I am printing my highchart in a lightbox window.

```
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'containerDivID',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
               categories: xDataValues

        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +' kr';
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                borderWidth: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        }
        ,
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
                }
            },
            title:{
                text: ''
            }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'YAxis',
            color: '#37789F',
            data: yDataValues
        }

        ],
        credits:{
            enabled: false
        }
    });
```

In this lightbox I have a print button on pressing this button I am calling window.print() to print the page. On my print page I can see the y and x axis and there data but cannot see my bar charts. But If I change IE8 mode from Compatible to IE8 standard mode then I can see my chart on printing.

Regards,
Andi

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you edit your question to include some code that you have so far. We can't solve your issue unless we can see what you have done in your code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi LydOn, Thanks for the quick reply. I have added the code snipet to better understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me I didn't use the `print()` function to print the chart as I need to print extra data with the chart; As my chart is part of a report.

kindly find the custom print function I wrote:

```
 function printReport() {
    w = window.open();
    var svg = myChart.getSVG();

    //clone the div you want to print which contains your chart
    var toprint = $('#bs-results') .clone();

    //replace the chart with the svg
    toprint.find('#graph_div').html(svg);

    //right the output to print it
    w.document.write(toprint.html());

    w.print();
    w.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please take look at compatibility page http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility, we support native browser but not compatibility mode.